Pandas compare() how to iterate over rows
I am comparing two dfs using pandas compare()
updated_records = out['df1'].compare(out['df2']) 

    userid       amount
  self other self other
0   122  121  NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN  3.0   4.0

how to efficiently iterate over those rows to have output some thing like this (there are more columns than those two it is only example) i want to point which columns to show in report [userid, amount, but not others ]:
First row:
UserId: 122 -> 121

Second row:
amount: 3.0 -> 4.0

I need output like for report:
"For item XXX_XXX those fields where updated:
UserId: 122 -> 121,
xyz: a -> b,
             "


"For item XXX_YYY those fields where updated:
amount: 3.0 -> 4.0,
xyz: 45 -> ert

Basicly to to show changes
i was trying iterrows() but df get pivoted to something like this
            other    2024-06-06T11:23:35
SaveTS       self     2024-06-06T10:36:53
             other    2024-06-06T11:23:40
A            self                     UP4
             other                    UP5
B            self     2025-02-07T00:00:00
             other    2025-02-08T00:00:00
C            self              7 FEB 2025
             other             8 FEB 2025
D            self     2025-02-07T00:00:00
             other    2025-02-08T00:00:00
E            self                     7.0
             other                    8.0

and got stuck, as above i want to select A,B,C,E only to show in changes report
thanks

If you assume your sample have other columns, include them as an example and provide desired output that can be derived from your sample. Also include code to generate an example data frame. (If your sample is multi-index, providing code to generate the sample is required.)

Example Code
It wasn't clear what exact output style you wanted, so I provided it as a new example.
import pandas as pd
data = {
    ('userid', 'self'): [122, None],
    ('userid', 'other'): [121, None],
    ('amount', 'self'): [None, 3.0],
    ('amount', 'other'): [2, 4.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0, 2])

df:

Code
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print('For item {} those fields where updated:'.format(idx))
    colums_lv0 = row[row.notna()].index.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates()
    for col in colums_lv0:        
        print('{} : {} -> {}'.format(col, row[(col, 'self')], row[(col, 'other')]))
    print()

print:
For item 0 those fields where updated:
userid : 122.0 -> 121.0
amount : nan -> 2.0

For item 2 those fields where updated:
amount : 3.0 -> 4.0


You can use this approach:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"userid": [122, 123, 124], "amount": [1, 2, 3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"userid": [121, 123, 124], "amount": [1, 2, 4]})

updated_records = df1.compare(df2)

main_cols = set([col[0] for col in updated_records.columns])

for col in main_cols:
    updated_records[f"{col}_comp"] = updated_records.apply(
        lambda row: f'{row[(col, "self")]} -> {row[(col, "other")]}', axis=1
    )

for i, row in updated_records.iterrows():
    print(f"Fields updated on row {i}:")
    for col in main_cols:
        updated = row[f"{col}_comp"].iloc[0]
        if "nan" not in updated:
            print(f"{col}: {updated}")
    print()

Fields updated on row 0:
userid: 122.0 -> 121.0

Fields updated on row 2:
amount: 3.0 -> 4.0

